# Storing messages and threads in Windows Azure Table Storage

Tags: asp.net, azure-storage

I am designing a simple messaging service using ASP.NET MVC / Windows Azure Table Storage. I have two kinds of entities - messages and message threads. Relation between them is simple - each thread can have multiple messages but the message can only be assigned to one thread.

Table storage is not a relational DB, so representing relations is always a bit tricky. I need to decide between 2 approaches:

1. Having one big table for threads and one for messages. And having threadId as a partition key of message entity so that messages are partitioned by threads.
2. Dynamically creating a special table for each message thread and having threadId as a name of the table.

I tend to prefer the second because it fits better into architecture of the rest of the service. But there will obviously be large number of tables created in a storage account.

Do you think this may be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a large number of tables may be an issue, depending on how you want to manage them.  The [underlying REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179405.aspx) for listing tables works like a query for table entities. It only returns the first 1000 tables, after that you have to use a continuation token.  All of the storage explorers I've seen don't allow you to query tables based on name, they simply like the first 1000 tables.  If you end up with 20000 threads, it could take you a while to get to the table you want.

One way you could mitigate this is to put your message table in its own storage account.  This way your storage account with all of your other tables won't get crowded out by all of these dynamic tables that you will be creating and possibly deleting.

Deleting is actually one of the ways in which using a separate table for each thread would be easier.  To delete all of the related messages you simply have to delete one table rather than iterating over each message and deleting it.

Everything else however will be more complicated than keeping all of the messages in one table.  If this is core functionality to your app and you can dedicate enough time to develop it this way, one table per thread is probably a good idea.  Otherwise the easy way to do things is with one big table.

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider having just one table, that stores both Thread and Message entities.  This would give you transaction support, and you could use Lucifure's hybrid approach on this table.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider a hybrid approach to keep the number of tables to a manageable level, depending on your scalability needs.

My experience has been that date based partitioning at the table level is a very effective approach and can be leverage across the board.

For example you could partition tables based on date and with a granularity of day or month. So a table name like “Thread201202” could be used for all threads **started** in February 2012.

Your thread id would implicitly include the “201202” and be something like “201202-myid01” although you would not need to explicitly store it in the partition key since it would be implied in the table name.

Aged threads could then be easily disposed by deleting tables say more than a year old.